# how to create chart control in code behind wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, code-behind, modern-ui

I have a chart control in xaml everythings work fine but now I want create this chart using code-behind:
this is my xaml:

```
<chart:ClusteredColumnChart>
    <chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series>
        <chart:ChartSeries
            Name = "chart"
            DisplayMember = "Date"
            ItemsSource = "{Binding}"
            ValueMember = "Scores" />
    </chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series>
</chart:ClusteredColumnChart >
```

I wrote this code but data not generate

```
ClusteredColumnChart chart = new ClusteredColumnChart();
ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries
{
    DisplayMember = "Date",
    ItemsSource = "{Binding}",
    ValueMember = "Scores"
};
series.ItemsSource = dt;
chart.Series.Add(series);
maingrid.Children.Add(chart);
```

What do I miss?
 In my opinion, in xaml codes 3 controls are inside each other

> chart:ClusteredColumnChart -->  chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series -->
>   chart:ChartSeries

but in Code-behind I couldnt find this 3 controls and just used 2 controls

> ClusteredColumnChart --> ChartSeries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use "{Binding}" in Code.

You have to create a Binding using

```
new System.Windows.Data.Binding(...)
```

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Update:
And to answer your second question: < chart:ClusteredColumnChart.Series > is an attribute not an object.

Update 2:
Binding example:

```
var b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding {Source = dt};
series.SetBinding(ChartSeries.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

Or if you want to set the ItemsSource directly just use this without any Bindings:

```
series.ItemsSource = dt;
```

Comment: i used this code var b = new Binding() { Source = dt }; itemsource = b; but not work get error cant convert binding to IEnumerable